# How to get curb error stacktrace

Tags: ruby, curl

How can I display the entire stacktrace where there is an error when using Curb's curl::easy?  I've tried looking at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/taf2/curb/Curl/Err to get information, but don't see anything.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/taf2/curb/Curl/Err is the list of possible errors that could be returned if Curb has a problem. If you need to trap for a specific exception or error you can use those in the `rescue` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
  curl.perform
rescue Curl::Err::CurlError => e
  puts e.backtrace.inspect # or log it
end
```

**UPDATE**

> I tried that however that didn't seem to give me a detailed error
>   message. Right now I'm getting a generic error message and it's hard
>   to debug

As Tin Man already mentioned *"rubydoc.info/github/taf2/curb/Curl/Err is the list of possible errors that could be returned if Curb has a problem."*.

To catch specific errors you need to rescue them individually. As you can see in my example above I am trying to rescue specifically [`Curl::Err::CurlError`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/taf2/curb/Curl/Err/CurlError). Similarly you can add more errors as follows:

```
rescue Curl::Err::CurlError => e
  puts "CURLERROR: === " + e.backtrace.inspect
rescue Curl::Err::AccessDeniedError => e
  puts "ACCESSDENIED: === " + e.backtrace.inspect
rescue Curl::Err::TimeoutError => e
  puts "TIMEOUT: === " + e.backtrace.inspect
...
end
```

Comment: I tried that however that didn't seem to give me a detailed error message. Right now I'm getting a generic error message and it's hard to debug.

Comment: "I'm getting a generic error message and it's hard to debug." Perhaps you should add that "generic error message" to your question and explain why it doesn't help you with what you want so we can help you with something specific? Format the message for readability.

Comment: @user2974739 adding to TinMan's comment, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: ....this is out of order - CurlError (the generic catch everything else) should be last - right now a timeout, for example, would trigger there, and not the TimeoutError section.  IME.